# How do I run in chroot environment temporarily in a C program?

Tags: c, linux, systems-programming, chroot

What I'm trying to do is essentially as follows:

```
some_function_1();
chroot("/some_other_root");
some_function_2();
//Get back to main root somehow...
some_function_3();
```

So that only some_function_2() runs in the chroot environment, but other code runs in the normal environment.

Is this sort of thing possible to do within one process?  Or will I need to fork into a new process to do this?

Comment: Do you intend to run with root privileges? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105/chroot-jail-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: @Yunnosch You don't need root privileges now that user namespaces exist, although you do have to do an interesting dance sometimes.

Comment: The link mentions that root can leave the chroot jail. That is why I ask about root privileges and why I think that the comment by @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. is not unconditionally applicable.

Comment: @Yunnosch you are right, I confused chroot with something else.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root directory is a property of the process.  Each process, in the user area, has two inodes, which are used to start the files search  parsing algorithm:

- The root directory inode is maintained in a reference in the user area of every process that has that directory as the root inode.
- The current working directory, is maintained also as a reference in the user area.

Both inodes are used as starting points to parse filenames starting with `/` (from the root inode), and not starting with `/` (for the current directory inode) respectively.

The change of the current directory requires only that the user has `x` permission on all the directories that are navigated (using the current root or current dir inodes as starting point)  but the `chroot()` system call requires the user root privileges, so it is not possible to do it on a normal user process.

Anyway, as you have probably guessed already, being a property of a process, a single function inside that process cannot have different root or current directory inodes.  So your plan is not possible, from my point of view.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to accomplish what I needed by forking a new process and just running a function in that forked process.

Comment: This is how it’s implemented in the shell. You start a subprocess that execs a program in the chrooted directory.